# How to bind v-for values to HTML attributes in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to attach the values I get from a v-for to attributes in the same tag but with no luck. Here's my code:

```
 <label 
      v-for="hashtag in hashtags" 
      v-bind:title=`You can filter with {hashtag}`
      v-bind:data-value="hashtag"
 ></label>
```

Basically the value goes to the `title` and `data-value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your title binding should have double quotes before and after the expression, and it seems that you want a string interpolation in title, but I don't think it will work.

try this (you can ommit v-bind cus `:` its a shorthand for it)

```
<label v-for="hashtag in hashtags"  :title="'You can filter with ' + hashtag" :data-value="hashtag">
   {{ hashtag }}
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5sqs5fsq/

Comment: one important thing to notice here is, if you use v-bing/`:`, the right side of the `=` must be a javascript valid expression, cus it will be evaluated by vue.
`:sum="5+5"` will be evaluated to number 10.
`sum="5+5"` will be evaluated to string `5+5`.
With string `:title="'a' +  'string'"` you need a single quote inside the double quote to make it work.